# Unable to calculate in navigation drawer

Tags: android

I have been trying to make one calculator in navigation drawer but it gives me an error and I could not be able to calculate.

How can I resolve this error?

```
public class SNFFragment extends Fragment {

    public SNFFragment() {
}

EditText edit1, edit2;
Button btn;
android.widget.TextView TextView;
double value1, value2;
double value3;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snf_layout, container, false);

    edit1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    edit2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit2);
    btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (edit1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                edit1.setError("Enter value1");
            } else if (edit2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                edit2.setError("Enter value2");
            } else {
                calculate();
            }

        }

        private void calculate() {
            try {
                value1 = Double.valueOf(edit1.getText().toString());
                value2 = Double.valueOf(edit2.getText().toString());

                Log.d("value1", String.valueOf(value1));
                Log.d("value2", String.valueOf(value2));

                value3 = (0.25 * value1 + value2 * 0.21 + 0.36);

                //When the button is clicked, call the calculate method.

                TextView.setText(String.format("Answer: %.2f", value3));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.d("value1", String.valueOf(value1));
                Log.d("value2", String.valueOf(value2));

                Log.d("Exception", String.valueOf(e));
            }
        });
         return view;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please include the error log.

Comment: You should move the `calculate()` function outside of the `onCreateView` method because it is just a helper method in your SNFFragment class.

Comment: error I am getting is Error:(77, 9) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(78, 9) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(79, 5) error: class, interface, or enum expected..What should be the probable code...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move the `calculate()` function outside of the `onClickListener` callback function and instead have it as a private function of your `SNFFragment` so that you code looks like this::

```
public class SNFFragment extends Fragment {

    public SNFFragment() {}

EditText edit1, edit2;
Button btn;
android.widget.TextView TextView;
double value1, value2;
double value3;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snf_layout, container, false);

    edit1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    edit2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit2);
    btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (edit1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                edit1.setError("Enter value1");
            } else if (edit2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                edit2.setError("Enter value2");
            } else {
                calculate();
            }
        } 
     });      

  return view;
}
 private void calculate() {
            try {
                value1 = Double.valueOf(edit1.getText().toString());
                value2 = Double.valueOf(edit2.getText().toString());

                Log.d("value1", String.valueOf(value1));
                Log.d("value2", String.valueOf(value2));

                value3 = (0.25 * value1 + value2 * 0.21 + 0.36);

                //When the button is clicked, call the calculate method.

                TextView.setText(String.format("Answer: %.2f", value3));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.d("value1", String.valueOf(value1));
                Log.d("value2", String.valueOf(value2));

                Log.d("Exception", String.valueOf(e));
            }
    }
}
```

Please give it a try and let us know if this helps.